# Refactoring Hibernate + JPA

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I might have stupid question but to be honest I have no idea how to look for informations I am intrested in.

I have two entities:

```
@Entity
@EntityScan
@Table(name = "codevuln")
@EntityListeners(AuditingEntityListener.class)
public class CodeVuln {
    private Long id;
    private CodeProject codeProject;
    private CodeGroup codeGroup;
    private String name;
    //settersandgetters
}
```

and

```
@Entity
@EntityScan
@Table(name = "webappvuln")
@EntityListeners(AuditingEntityListener.class)
public class WebAppVuln {

    private Long id;
    private WebAppScan webAppScan;
    private WebApp webApp;
    private String name;
    //settersandgetters
}
```

I would like to make of it one entity like that:

```
@Entity
@EntityScan
@Table(name = "vuln")
@EntityListeners(AuditingEntityListener.class)
public class Vuln{

    private Long id;
    private WebAppScan webAppScan;
    private WebApp webApp;
    private CodeProject codeProject;
    private CodeGroup codeGroup;
    private VulnType vulnType;
    private String name;
    //settersandgetters
}
```

with as little as possible work to do (because there is so many other services using `CodeVuln` and `WebAppVuln` classes and queries which are different for both repositories)

Is it somehow possible to migrate data to one entity and point both `WebAppVuln` and `CodeVuln` to `@Table(name="Vuln")` but whenever I will use `WebAppVulnRepository` for prepared query it will use prequisite of `VulnType=WebApp` ?

Comment: Make an composit entity.